# How can I make this function work for 100 objects(c++)?

Tags: c++

So I have a program that shows the numbers in a text file of each object, the problem is that the original program is with only 6 objects, which I found preety easy, but now I have to change it to work with 100 objects. I tried using a for loop but it only showed me the first object. I don't have much experience programming and have tried other ways but none of them work. Anyways, here's the function:

```
void Circle::writeAll(Circle circle[6], int &count) {
if (count == 0) {
    cout << "No circles in file. " << endl << endl;
};
if (count == 1 || count == 2 || count == 3 || count == 4 || count == 5 || count == 6) {
    cout << " Radius: " << circle[0].getRadius() << "; Center(x): " << circle[0].getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle[0].getCentery() << endl;
};
if (count == 2 || count == 3 || count == 4 || count == 5 || count == 6) {
    cout << " Radius: " << circle[1].getRadius() << "; Center(x): " << circle[1].getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle[1].getCentery() << endl;
};
if (count == 3 || count == 4 || count == 5 || count == 6) {
    cout << " Radius: " << circle[2].getRadius() << "; Center(x): "  << circle[2].getCenterx() << "; Centery(y): " << circle[2].getCentery() << endl;
};
if (count == 4 || count == 5 || count == 6){
  cout << " Radio: " << circle[3].getRadius() << "; Center(x): " << circle[3].getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle[3].getCentery() << endl;  
};
if (count == 5 || count == 6){
  cout << " Radius: " << circle[4].getRadius() << "; Center(x): " << circle[4].getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle[4].getCentery() << endl;  
};
if (count == 6){
  cout << " Radio: " << circle[5].getRadius() << "; Center(x): " << circle[5].getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle[5].getCentery() << endl;  
};
cout << endl;
```

};

Comment: Why is a `Circle` object taking a container of `Circle`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array I would use a built in container type like `std::vector`. In this case it would look like this:

```cpp
void Circle::writeAll(const std::vector<Circle>& circles)
{
    size_t size = circles.size();

    if (size == 0)
    {
        cout << "no circles in file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // print all the circles
    for (auto& circle : circles)
    {
        cout << " Radio: " << circle.getRadius() << "; Center(x): " << circle.getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle.getCentery() << endl;
    }
}
```

It seemed to me you are trying to print every object until the number `count` is reached.

Well this will do the same but with a `vector` of `Circle` objects.

And as @Josh said if I misunderstood something, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do: (unless I'm not getting the problem right)

```
void Circle::writeAll(Circle circle[], int &count,int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if(count == 0)
            cout << "No circles in file. " << endl << endl;
        else if(count == i)
            cout << " Radius: " << circle[i-1].getRadius() << "; Center(x):"
            << circle[i].getCenterx() << "; Center(y): " << circle[i-1].getCentery() << endl;
    }
}
```

however you will need to send in a `size` parameter
if the solution is not clear feel free to comment

Comment: So, I did that and it worked pretty well but the only problem is that if I use that same option twice on the menu, it shows the radius and other values of the circle as = 0. Maybe there is an easy way  to fix  that but then again, I'm new to c++ so I don't know how to solve it.